# EXTRACT DUPLICATES VALUES BY YEAR WITHOUT GROUP BY SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I try to extract all the possible NUMB's duplicate values that is in the same year, this is an example

| NUMB | TIP_BALAN | FNT | CLOSED_DATE | DURATION |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 94294100000 | A03 | E04 | 31/10/2021 | 15 |
| 94294100000 | A09 | E04 | 31/08/2021 | 20 |

so i build this query on Oracle SQL Developer

```
SELECT ID_PPAL_NUMB AS NUMB,
ID_PPAL_FNT AS FNT,
BLNC_CLOSED_DATE AS CLOSED_DATE,
BLNC_DUR AS DURATION
FROM BLNC_BALANC

    INNER JOIN ID_PPAL
    ON BLNC_ID_PPAL_NUMB=ID_PPAL_NUMB

    WHERE BLNC_SIT='1'
    AND ID_PPAL_TIP_REG='1'
    AND ID_PPAL_IND_ESTAB='N'

GROUP BY (ID_PPAL_NUMB,ID_PPAL_FNT, BLNC_CLOSED_DATE, BLNC_DUR)
HAVING COUNT(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM BLNC_CLOSED_DATE)) > 1
ORDER BY BLNC_CLOSED_DATE DESC
```

and I had 42 columns but when I add the column "BLNC_TIP" from BLNC_BALANC with the next query

```
SELECT ID_PPAL_NUMB AS NUMB,
BLNC_TIP AS TIP_BALAN,
ID_PPAL_FNT AS FNT,
BLNC_CLOSED_DATE AS CLOSED_DATE,
BLNC_DUR AS DURATION
FROM BLNC_BALANC

    INNER JOIN ID_PPAL
    ON BLNC_ID_PPAL_NUMB=ID_PPAL_NUMB

    WHERE BLNC_SIT='1'
    AND ID_PPAL_TIP_REG='1'
    AND ID_PPAL_IND_ESTAB='N'

GROUP BY (ID_PPAL_NUMB,ID_PPAL_FNT, BLNC_CLOSED_DATE, BLNC_DUR, BLNC_TIP)
HAVING COUNT(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM BLNC_CLOSED_DATE)) > 1
ORDER BY BLNC_CLOSED_DATE DESC
```

The query give me just 6 columns so I was trying multiple ways to avoid the "Group by" code but I just have the entire data like 15k columns. Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not want to use `GROUP BY` then you could use the `COUNT` analytic function:

```sql
SELECT numb,
       fnt,
       closed_date,
       duration,
       blnc_tip
FROM   (
  SELECT ID_PPAL_NUMB AS NUMB,
         ID_PPAL_FNT AS FNT,
         BLNC_CLOSED_DATE AS CLOSED_DATE,
         BLNC_DUR AS DURATION,
         BLNC_TIP,
         COUNT(*) OVER (
           PARTITION BY ID_PPAL_NUMB, EXTRACT(YEAR FROM BLNC_CLOSED_DATE)
         ) AS cnt
  FROM   BLNC_BALANC
         INNER JOIN ID_PPAL
         ON BLNC_ID_PPAL_NUMB = ID_PPAL_NUMB
  WHERE  BLNC_SIT          = '1'
  AND    ID_PPAL_TIP_REG   = '1'
  AND    ID_PPAL_IND_ESTAB = 'N'
  ORDER BY BLNC_CLOSED_DATE DESC
)
WHERE  cnt > 1  -- Move the `HAVING` clause to a `WHERE` filter in an outer query.
```

Note 1:

`COUNT(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM BLNC_CLOSED_DATE))` is counting the number of rows where the year of `BLNC_CLOSED_DATE` is not a `NULL` value. It is the same as `COUNT(BLNC_CLOSED_DATE)` (since you will only get a `NULL` year if you have a `NULL` date value). It does **not** count the number of rows per year; if you want that then, in your query, you need to use `COUNT(*)` and add `EXTRACT(YEAR FROM BLNC_CLOSED_DATE)` to the `GROUP BY` clause.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `blnc_tip` has many distinct values which results in that many **rows** (rows, not *columns*).

You didn't explain what it represents (and we don't have your tables), but - what you could do - is to somehow **aggregate** that column's values. For example, if it were a `NUMBER` datatype and you wanted to get *total*, you'd `sum(blnc_tip)`:

```
  SELECT id_ppal_numb AS numb,
         SUM (blnc_tip) AS tip_balan,        --> aggregate BLNC_TIP
         id_ppal_fnt AS fnt,
         blnc_closed_date AS closed_date,
         blnc_dur AS duration
    FROM blnc_balanc INNER JOIN id_ppal ON blnc_id_ppal_numb = id_ppal_numb
   WHERE     blnc_sit = '1'
         AND id_ppal_tip_reg = '1'
         AND id_ppal_ind_estab = 'N'
GROUP BY id_ppal_numb,
         id_ppal_fnt,
         blnc_closed_date,
         blnc_dur
  HAVING COUNT (EXTRACT (YEAR FROM blnc_closed_date)) > 1
ORDER BY blnc_closed_date DESC;
```

Or, maybe you would be happy with its `max` value:

```
   `max(blnc_tip)`
```

or even *list* all `blnc_tip`s within group of all other values contained in the `group by` clause:

```
    listagg(blnc_tip, ', ') within group (order by null)
```

(note that `listagg` is restricted to max 4000 characters).

---

Basically, it depends on what you want to do with `blnc_tip`.